# Widgets disappear when moving the window rapidly

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-label

I noticed this behavior, where moving the window rapidly made the widgets in it disappear.

[image]

```py
import tkinter as tk

hidden=tk.Tk()
hidden.attributes('-alpha',0.0)

root=tk.Toplevel(hidden)

bg_label=tk.Label(root)
bg_label.pack()

label=tk.Label(bg_label,text='Example')
label.pack(padx=100,pady=100)

hidden.mainloop()
```

**DESCRIPTION**

Basically I am having a transparent window as the main `Tk()` instance, so that I can have its visibility in the taskbar, as I am using a custom title bar with `overrideredirect(True)` on its parent window. I have a background label with some image (image not being a contributing factor) and another label packed in it.

**OBSERVATIONS**

- The widgets packed in the background label disappear on rapid motion of the window.
- The widgets are restored on minimizing and re-opening.
- This doesn't happen if the `attributes('-alpha',)` of the `Toplevel()` is anything less than 1.

**ADDITIONAL**

[image: disappearing label]

*Below are the actual codes (they are not needed to reproduce the behavior)*

Here is the code for the above example

```py
from gui import *

hidden=tk.Tk()
hidden.attributes('-alpha',0.0)

root=tk.Toplevel(hidden)
screen_height=root.winfo_screenheight()
req_height=screen_height//2
req_width=req_height*16//9
root.geometry(f'{req_width}x{req_height+32}+100+100')

tb=TitleBar(root,hidden,fg='white',bg='black',font=('Arial',10))
tb.pack()

img_path=os.path.join('data','images')
bg_image=Image.open(os.path.join(img_path,'example.png'))
bg_image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(bg_image.resize((req_width,req_height),Image.ANTIALIAS))

bg_label=tk.Label(root,bd=0,image=bg_image)
bg_label.pack(fill='both',expand=True)

teacher_button_image=Image.open(os.path.join(img_path,'teacher_button.png'))
teacher_button_image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(teacher_button_image.resize((100,32),Image.ANTIALIAS))
teacher_label=tk.Label(bg_label,image=teacher_button_image)
teacher_label.pack(pady=(200,0))

hidden.mainloop()
```

And here is the relevant part of `gui.py`

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
import os
import webbrowser

class TitleBar:
    def __init__(self,parent,hidden,icon=None,title='App',width=10,bg=None,fg=None,font=None,iconlink=None):

        def get_pos(event):
            xwin = self.parent.winfo_x()
            ywin = self.parent.winfo_y()
            startx = event.x_root
            starty = event.y_root
            ywin = ywin - starty
            xwin = xwin - startx

            def move_window(event):
                self.parent.geometry('+{0}+{1}'.format(event.x_root+xwin, event.y_root+ywin))

            self.title_frame.bind('<B1-Motion>',move_window)

        def on_iconify(event):
            if self.parent.state()=='normal':
                self.parent.withdraw()
            else:
                on_deiconify(None)

        def on_deiconify(event):
            self.parent.deiconify()

        def dest(evrnt):
            self.parent.destroy()
            self.hidden.destroy()

        def on_enter_close(event):
            self.close_label.config(image=self.close_title_button_hover)

        def on_leave_close(event):
            self.close_label.config(image=self.close_title_button)

        def on_enter_minimise(event):
            self.minimise_label.config(image=self.minimise_title_button_hover)

        def on_leave_minimise(event):
            self.minimise_label.config(image=self.minimise_title_button)

        def icon_link(event):
            if self.iconlink:
                webbrowser.open(self.iconlink)

        self.width=width
        self.parent=parent
        self.hidden=hidden
        self.icon=icon
        self.iconlink=iconlink

        self.close_title_button=ImageTk.PhotoImage(close_title_button.resize((self.width,self.width),Image.ANTIALIAS))
        self.close_title_button_hover=ImageTk.PhotoImage(close_title_button_hover.resize((self.width,self.width),Image.ANTIALIAS))
        self.minimise_title_button_hover=ImageTk.PhotoImage(minimise_title_button_hover.resize((self.width,self.width),Image.ANTIALIAS))
        self.minimise_title_button=ImageTk.PhotoImage(minimise_title_button.resize((self.width,self.width),Image.ANTIALIAS))
        self.title_frame=tk.Frame(self.parent,bg=bg)
        if icon:
            self.logo_icon=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(self.icon).resize((self.width+10,self.width+10),Image.ANTIALIAS))
            self.logo_label=tk.Label(self.title_frame,image=self.logo_icon,bd=0,bg=bg,cursor='hand2')
            self.logo_label.pack(side='left',padx=(10,5))
            self.logo_label.bind('<Button-1>',icon_link)
        self.title_label=tk.Label(self.title_frame,text=title,bg=bg,fg=fg,font=font)
        self.title_label.pack(side='left')
        self.close_label=tk.Label(self.title_frame,image=self.close_title_button,bd=0,bg=bg)
        self.close_label.pack(side='right',ipadx=10,ipady=11)
        self.close_label.bind('<Button-1>',dest)
        self.close_label.bind('<Enter>',on_enter_close)
        self.close_label.bind('<Leave>',on_leave_close)
        self.minimise_label=tk.Label(self.title_frame,image=self.minimise_title_button,bd=0,bg=bg)
        self.minimise_label.pack(side='right',ipadx=10,ipady=11)
        self.minimise_label.bind('<Button-1>',on_iconify)
        self.minimise_label.bind('<Enter>',on_enter_minimise)
        self.minimise_label.bind('<Leave>',on_leave_minimise)
        self.title_frame.bind('<Button-1>',get_pos)
        self.title_label.bind('<Button-1>',get_pos)
        self.hidden.bind('<Map>',on_deiconify)
        self.hidden.bind('<Unmap>',on_iconify)

    def pack(self):
        self.parent.overrideredirect(True)
        self.parent.geometry('+100+100')
        self.title_frame.pack(side='top',anchor='e',fill='x')
        if self.icon:
            self.parent.iconphoto(False,self.logo_icon)
            self.hidden.iconphoto(False,self.logo_icon)
```

I would love to know the reason for the same and how to prevent this, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's a lot of code. Are you certain it is all required to duplicate the problem? For example, can you remove the calls to `iconphoto` and the other image functions? Can you remove all of the bindings? Does the problem still exist if you only have a single label or single button? See here for how to write a [mcve].

Comment: @BryanOakley Apologies, I realized most of it was unnecessary, thanks for the suggestion, I have provided a short code that does the same behavior

Comment: There still seems to be a lot of extra code. Again, it would be best if you can remove the images. If removing the images makes the problem go away, we know the root cause. And if removing the images doesn't change anything, they clearly aren't needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @BryanOakley I did remove all of that, it's now only a plain window with a single label, please check the *The minimum code required to reproduce this* part of my question.

Comment: 6 months into this, is it still reproducible? I do not get this issue. It could be some rendering issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in below line.

```
bg_label=tk.Label(root)
```

You should replace it with the following:

```
bg_label=tk.Frame(root)
```

Comment: How did you come to this conclusion?